# How to add numbers in an array stored in a file python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, file

So I am trying to add numbers stored in a variable that is saved in a file.

```
if rw == "s":
    fo = open("foo.txt", "w")
    while int(count) != 0:
        x = input("Input a number for storage ")
        count = int(count) - 1
        test.append(int(x))
        print("")
    fo.write("%s" % test)
    fo.close()

fo = open("foo.txt", "r")
add = int(fo.readlines(1)) + int(fo.readlines(2))
```

I do not quite understand how the last part works. The error I get is the following:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

The content of the file looks something like this:
`[6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 3]`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the first and second value of the list and add them together do this

```
content = fo.readlines(1)
content = content[0].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
numbers = content.split(", ")
add = int(numbers[0]) + int(numbers[1])
```

Explanation:

`readlines` reads all the lines in the file and returns a list. 
`readlines(index)` will return a list with only the selected line. Either case, you can't call `int()` on it.

Comment: I see, it worked. If I wanted to add other numbers I would need to change `content` or not?

Comment: The numbers array will contain all the numbers you added in string format. You can index into it to get any of them, but don't forget to convert it to int